# Searching for Office add-ins

Tags: c#, registry, ms-office, add-in

I'm looking to create a utility which searches for Office add-ins.

I've located some add-ins I have in my registry, so I think that would be a good place to start, but I couldn't just add the code to find my add-ins as there are hundreds more in the world, I'm stuck trying to find a way to search through the registry, therefore any advice would be much appreciated.

What I have found:

Office add-ins are located in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office` so I'm wanting to iterate through that key, to return the values of the Manifest Location, Load Behavior, Description etc.

I'd like some help to point me in the right direction, If I haven't made myself clear enough please comment and I will happily answer your question.

Comment: IIRC there used to be some sub-directory in the installation directory of Microsoft Office where add-ins could be deployed, too. Perhaps you could scan that directory in addition to (or even instead of) the registry?

Comment: You could use `Registry.GetValue` or `RegistryKey.GetValue` Method to retrieve registry information. Take a look on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue.aspx | http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzxd58z1.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (RegistryKey ExcelLocation = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins"))

        foreach (string subKeyName in ExcelLocation.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            // Open the key.
            using (RegistryKey subKey = ExcelLocation.OpenSubKey(subKeyName))
            {
                // Write the value.
                Console.Writeline(subKey.GetValue("Description"));
                Console.Writeline(subKey.GetValue("FriendlyName"));
                Console.Writeline(subKey.GetValue("Manifest"));
            }
        }
```

This is the closest I'm going to get to retrieving the information about the addins It retrieves the information I wanted to extract from the registry.